# How to add version info to Windows Service installed via Sc.exe tool?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

When you install Windows Service via the wizard (using `.msi` file), Windows will add a record in `Add or remove programs` with a version number, that you can set in properties of the Wizard project.

You can also install Windows Service, using `Sc.exe` tool.

My question is, how to install windows service via Sc.exe tool and still have a record in `Add or remove programs` with a version. So I know what version of Windows Service is running. Ideal scenario would be to include the version in the code. So that `Sc.exe` will call `MyService.exe` without any parameters.

Thanks for help,

Comment: The SC.exe tool only manipulates the Windows services. It does not alter the Add/Remove programs list as the two are not related. Some ideas would be to make your own installation routine, which has 2 approaches. One would be a program that installs the service and adds the necessary registry settings to the Add//Remove programs (this is similar to what the MSI is doing). Another approach would be (assuming the service is written in .NET) to add a service installer to your .NET service. Then, you could use the .NET installutil.exe to install the service instead of sc.exe.

Comment: ...   The service installer could then run custom code to add the necessary registry settings to the Add/Remove programs.

Comment: @Wiz so how should versioning be handled in Windows Service? I'm kinda confused. It must have a version

Comment: Like @Wiz mentioned, Windows service has no version at all. The version you see belongs to what the installer registered in Windows (registry for example), and that's why an installer (like MSI) is needed.

Comment: @robertwojnar can you explain what you are trying to use the version number for? The service points to an exe. The exe itself should have a version number. The version in add/remove programs is usually a version of the install routine or package of files for a product. For example you may install a product that could consist of 4 exe files, 5 dll files and 2 services. Each part may have a different version number but belong to a specific version of the package/product.

Comment: @Wiz I need a version number for maintance. It's a production service, how should I handle versioning? I'm completely confused